# Discrepancy in Spam Flags numbers in flagging history

Tags: support, spam, flag-history

On my flagging history on SO, I have the following spam flags numbers:

```
387 posts marked spam
377 deemed helpful
4 declined
```

I have no *recent* spam flags that have not been handled. By 'recent', I mean within the last few months. It seems unlikely that there could be very old spam flags that haven't been handled one way or another.

So, what happened to the other 6? Were they eaten by a hungry unicorn? Did something else happen to the posts which caused the flags not to be handled at all?

Comment: Perhaps the posts were deleted manually by the OP before they could be deleted by the flags or a moderator. I would have thought that that would validate the flag, but it might be a special case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until not all that long ago, spam flags weren't considered either helpful or declined when the spam post was just deleted. The only way to mark them as helpful was for a moderator or 5 other users to flag explicitly as spam as well.

And even longer before that, there was no history at all whether the flag was helpful or not, so very old flags won't appear as helpful or declined.

I suspect that this is the reason for the discrepancy, I have a similar one in my flag history.

Comment: That makes sense; it has been a while that the number of the discrepancy has remained exactly at 6, except when I have pending spam flags (I assume)